# How to Import a KML file into Android Application with GMaps API

Tags: java, android, maps, kml

i have a simple application with Google Maps API instead and i have a KML file with 1000 marker that i want to display in the MAP of my Application.

How can i import a KML file in my map?

I use Android Studio

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load a KML dataset from a local resource, it's like this:

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

If you want to load a KML dataset from a local stream, it's like this:

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), kmlInputStream, getApplicationContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

More details in the [Maps Andriod API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml).

Answer (score 2):

You need to render the map and add a KML layer on top of it. Example:

```
KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.coordinates, getApplicationContext());
kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
```

Refer to [this](https://github.com/UmangChamaria/CivicApiDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/civic/civicapidemo/ui/activity/KMLActivity.java) github sample project for the complete sample